# Inserting nodes at split and merges of directed acyclic graphs

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have the following directed acyclic graph where edge directions are from top to bottom

```
                A
                |  
                B
               / \  
              C   D
             / \  |    
            E   F | 
             \ /  | 
              G   |
               \ /
                H
```

and I want to insert special split nodes where the nodes split and merge nodes where they merge again, i.e, I want the above graph structure to be transformed into the graph below

```
                A
                |
                B  
                | 
               B-S
               / \  
              C   D
              |   |  
             C-S  |  
             / \  |    
            E   F | 
             \ /  | 
             C-M  |
              |   | 
              G   |
               \ /
               B-M 
                |
                H
```

How can I do the above transformation?

Comment: I dont get the naming, for example why is there `S` in the `B-S` and at the end, why is there `B-M` and not `B-S` when this is part where these two merged?

Comment: `B-S` is `B` split and `B-M` is the merge node that was split at `B-S`. Same goes for `C-S` and `C-M`

Comment: The names can be anything like they can be `split1` and `merge1`. But `split1` must merge exactly at `merge1`.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? If you know howto draw it what is the problem to do the same on the graph structure?

Comment: the problem is matching the splits and merges. We can add split nodes if a node has more than one successor. Similarly, we can add a merge node whenever a node has more than one predecessor. But the problem is to identify the matching split at each merge.

Comment: @MuhammadAdeelZahid - thanks, more sense now. The tree is at most binary? (maxium of two children nodes)

Comment: @libik- No, it can have more than two children

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will rewrite the picture as this, so its clear which `M` and `S` are related. I am also considering the tree to have maximum of two children, but it can easily be updated to more children in merging part.

```
            A
            |
            B  
            | 
           B-S1
           / \  
          C   D
          |   |  
         C-S2 |  
         / \  |    
        E   F | 
         \ /  | 
         C-M2 |
          |   | 
          G   |
           \ /
           B-M1
            |
            H
```

The main principle is that when you do the split, you have to carry through all the other nodes the information about that until you merge them again.

The alghoritm will be as following:

Start: Create `stack` variable and push `A` to it together with empty `tokenStack` (it will be like one object `{node: A, tokenStack: {}}`

1. Take `item` from `stack`
2. Check number of parents with `item.parents.length`

   - If it is 2, check if `item.token` exists

     - If not, take last item from `tokenStack` and save it inside `item.token`

       - Skip everything else below and continue from 1.
     - If there is value existing, it should be same as your last value in `tokenStack`. Take that value out of your `tokenStack` and you can continue with 3.
3. Check number of children with `item.childrens.length`

   - If equal to 1, push that children to `stack` together with unchanged `tokenStack`
   - If there are two children, do the split, create token (i.e. unique string), add this token to `tokenStack`, save it to current `item.token` and push both children to `stack` together with `tokenStack`

Now you did it all and Split and Merge nodes have the same `item.token`

note: You can also save information about all the existing tokens in `tokenStack` during the flow if you want later investigate which nodes are in left/right part of which split branches.

Comment: In what order do I have to visit the vertices, topological sort, dfs or bfs from start node `A`?

Comment: @MuhammadAdeelZahid - actually in this case it does not matter which one you use, because this part `Skip everything else below and continue from 1` will basically cut the progressing of this part until the second part of merging appears. In example I provided, if you follow it and using standard stack (last in, first out) it will behave as DFS